# What are the meanings given by Satya Sai to various names of Arjuna?

Tags: arjuna, sai

Satya Sai baba gave very insightful meanings into each name of Arjuna. What are the meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satya Sai Baba gives meanings of various names of Arjuna.

http://www.vahini.org/Discourses/d8-bhagavadgita.html

Question 15:

> Arjuna: One who is pure and unsullied
>
> Prithâ: One who is the son of
> Pritvi the earth, that is, one who is the representative of mankind.
> (Prithâ: Queen Kuntî, mother of Arjuna)
>
> Kaunteya: One who can listen
> with rapt attention to the divine teaching.
>
> Gudakes'a: One who punishes the enemies
>
> Kurunandana: One who delights in work (action).
>
> Anasûya: One who is free from jealousy.
>
> Parantapa: One who strikes fear in the hearts of his enemies.
>
> Vijaya: One who is ever victorious.
>
> Danañjaya: One who has earned the merit to receive the wealth of
> spiritual wisdom.

Comment: [Kurunandana](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=kurunandana&direct=se) simply means 'descendant of Kuru'. Not sure how it can mean 'One who delights in work (action)'.

Comment: kuru means action from bg 18.63, nandana means delight.. @sv.